# How can I link a C declaration against a symbol in a non-standard section?

Tags: c, linker, llvm, undefined-symbol

I'm trying to work with [LLVM's stack map intrinsics](https://llvm.org/docs/StackMaps.html), and I'm having trouble figuring out how to process the generated data from a C program. For a minimal example, I have the following files:

`st.ll`:

```llvm
declare void @llvm.experimental.stackmap(i64, i32, ...)

define i32 @some_func(i32 %x) {
  %y = add i32 %x, %x
  call void(i64, i32, ...) @llvm.experimental.stackmap(i64 3735928559, i32 0, i32 %x, i32 %y)
  ret i32 %y
}
```

`ex.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

extern char __LLVM_StackMaps;

int main(void) {
    fwrite(&__LLVM_StackMaps, sizeof(char), 10, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

If I run `clang -c st.ll` and then examine the resulting object file with `nm -f s st.o`, I get the following output:

```
Symbols from st.o:

Name                  Value           Class        Type         Size             Line  Section

__LLVM_StackMaps    |0000000000000000|   r  |            NOTYPE|                |     |.llvm_stackmaps
some_func           |0000000000000000|   T  |              FUNC|0000000000000018|     |.text
```

Clearly, a `__LLVM_StackMaps` symbol is being generated. However, if I run `clang st.ll ex.c` or `clang st.o ex.c`, I get this error:

```
/tmp/ex-06d9d2.o: In function `main':
ex.c:(.text+0xb): undefined reference to `__LLVM_StackMaps'
clang-5.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

As far as I'm able to work out, the problem is that the symbol is in the `.llvm_stackmaps` section instead of in `.data` or `.bss`.

How can I resolve this? Is there a way to specify the source section in the C? Can I tell the linker to resolve from the `.llvm_stackmaps` section?

Comment: Why do you need that `__LLVM_StackMaps` symbol? I suspect, it is not intended to be used directly from C code.

Comment: I need it in order to do stack traversal so that I can implement a garbage collector. At this point in time, though, I mostly just want to try playing around in a debugger using the map as a guide, so I wanted to pull in the map and parse the data into a nicer format.

Comment: Then, I think, you need to write a thin "runtime" layer directly in LLVM IR, that would perform calls to stackmap intrinsics. Then use helpers from runtime to do something on the C side.

Comment: Yes, I'm generating the map using stackmap intrinsics, but you shouldn't need a runtime to access the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue—the section has nothing to do with it; it's just that the `__LLVM_StackMaps` symbol is local (as evidenced by `nm` reporting it with class `r` rather than `R`). I tried compiling `st.ll` to assembly first and manually adding a `.globl` before assembling it, and it linked fine.

Comment: Wouldn't it be an error, if you try to link two objects files with global `__LLVM_StackMaps`?

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not defining a global `__LLVM_StackMaps` in `ex.c`, I'm declaring one with `extern`.

Answer (score 1):

The gnu::section attribute should do it. clang also apparently supports gcc-style **attribute**((section("...")) and msvc-style __declspec(allocate("...")) syntaxes that perform the same operation.

[gnu::section("....")] void my_func(long, long);

Comment: I tried changing the `extern` line to `extern char __LLVM_StackMaps __attribute__ ((section (".llvm_stackmaps")));` (also tried without the `.`), but it still fails—I think that attribute is only for specifying where to *place* the symbol, not where to look it up.